# Problem with camera warping the background In Blender

Tags: animation, 3d-view, camera, scene

[image]I am really struggling with the following problem :

I am making an animation and for some reason my camera does not view ( deforms-warps ) the background(studio set as seen in the picture ) and whatever I do ( scale it , drag it closer ) the background ends up being split up.

I tried changing the focal length and increasing the END distance of the camera but nothing changes.

Anyone an idea what's wrong?

Thanks
Kasper

Comment: I don't understand the problem exactly. From what I understand, the backdrop isn't visible from the camera? Can't you just orient the camera to face the correct way?

Comment: The backdrop indeed gets deformed when looking trough the camera . any direction I point the camera to , whatever angle ... the backdrop just stays deformed and it does not fit for some reason . I just deleted the camera and inserted a new one since I could not find the problem. But now it is restored to the default state so its ok . Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Well I would have been curious to see that blend file though. Well..